# Unable to delete printer, status stays on 'Deleting - Offline'

Tags: windows-vista, printer

On Windows Vista, after right-clicking on a printer and choosing to delete it, the printer stays on 'Deleting - Offline'. Even after several restarts, the printer remains there.

Is there a way to definitely delete the printer?

Comment: Read our FAQ next time please.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? (I'm being serious)

Comment: @Chopper3: Seeing as you can ask questions about 'Desktop PCs that you maintain in the workplace' on ServerFault (quote from the faq, which I did read), I thought it was an OK place to ask. Fair enough.

Comment: @slhck: yes, these printers have been in the list for months. As I mentioned in my question, I have rebooted (but I used the word 'restarts', sorry for the confusion). I've even tried deleting them several times.

Comment: @Peter Oh, I somehow must have missed that, my bad. But basically, these printers are not physically there anymore, right?

Comment: Indeed, the printer is no longer physically attached to the pc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution myself, by accident. Right-clicked on the printer, chose the option 'Cancel all documents', and the printer dissappeared.

Comment: Cool, my problem is just same as yours and your hints solved my problem. About 7 printers disappeared. One of the printer still showing up. I opened Services.msc, stop the "Print Spooler" service, delete all documents at C:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS. Restart "Print Spooler" service, then the last printer disappeared as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

- This steps worked for me:
- Open "Administrative Tools", then "Print Management"
- Select "All Printers"
  -Find the printer in question -the status will be something like "Deleting - Offline" and there was 1 pending job. I right-clicked, selected "Cancel All Jobs", and the printer immediately disappeared.